# PHP Google Protobuf lib - Error occurred during parsing: Unexpected wire type

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, protocol-buffers, google-cloud-composer

Here's my step to catch this issue:

1. Install `google/analytics-data` + `google/protobuf` libraries (by Composer).
2. Everything still good when using `google-data-api` from local.
3. Deploy the project (with vendor folder - we're not run composer install when project is running build) to server.
4. Catch **"Error occurred during parsing: Unexpected wire type."** when using `google/analytics-data`.

So I've found 1 solution to fixed, that is remove the `google/protobuf` folder in vendor and reinstall it. But It's not inappropriate with my case (build without running composer install).

So do you have any other solution for this? Thanks for your help.